# Change Button Text Color for Button in Footer in Table View

Tags: xcode, uiview, uibutton, uicolor

I have a UIView that I've made into a button that's added below my Table View:

```
myUIView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120,50)];
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton setAutoResizingMask:  [UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleHeight];
[myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20,0,80,40)];

myButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; //Doesn't seem to work

[myButton setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[myUIView addSubView:myButton];
```

No matter what I try, the font always seems to be white. What can I do to change the font's color?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use setTitleColor: forState:

```
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```